# Error restoring files from backup using backup exec 2010 error code e000fee1

Tags: backup, restore, backupexec

Hopefully some had experiencing same problem like me using symatec backup exec 2010 r2.

We are using this software for backup and it not had problem until now, but lately when I want to restore files from incremental backup it always fail with error e000fee1.

Following the error message I get from the backup program:

> Error category    : Resource Errors
>   
> Error         : e000fee1 - A failure occurred writing an object

Is it error cause by hardware issue (e.g. bad sector on target disk).

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Why don't you open a support case with Veritas?

Comment: the thing's quite complicated, i am administrator in branch office so this backup server actually managed from our head quarter and they had the product key. I already inform but they answer it with not related question therefore I seek other method by visiting forum. I also already search for related case but no luck.

Comment: they answer it with just restore it with volume shadow copy that in my case not the answer I want because I am afraid if this server had disaster i can not rely from shadow copy anymore.